# How to set different date title in toolbar on every different click on date in calendar?

Tags: java, android, date, datepicker, calendar

In this activity, calendar view is set. When I clicked on any date, it opened a new activity but in toolbar it shows only current date.  I want to show that date, month, and year, which clicked in calendar and every different date open same activity but edittext should be different.

```
public class DiaryFragment extends Fragment {

   

        // Add Listener in calendar
        cale
        return view;
    }
}

   @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()){
                case caledartextpost:
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    calendartextview.setCursorVisible(false);
                    break;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);


    }
}
```

Comment: if you want to pass a date from one activity to another .. make a use `Intent` instead...........

Comment: But how can i pass data to toolbar of different activity from a fragment

Comment: added answer.......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**set different date title in toolbar on every different click on date in calendar**

i have done using intent

### Here's a demo for you :--

> > **Fragment Activity:---**

```
public class FragmentActivity extends Fragment {
TextView dateView;
 CalendarView calendar;

public FragmentActivity() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_menu1, container, false);

}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    dateView = view.findViewById(R.id.dateView);
    calendar = view.findViewById(R.id.calender);
    calendar.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onSelectedDayChange(@NonNull CalendarView view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            String Date = dayOfMonth + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + year;

            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), AnotherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("name", Date);
            startActivity(intent);
            dateView.setText(Date);
        }
    });

}
 }
```

> > **AnotherActivity.java:----**

```
public class AnotherActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView textView;
Toolbar toolbar;
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.next);
    textView=findViewById(R.id.display);
    toolbar=findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String name = intent.getStringExtra("name");

        textView.setText(name);
        toolbar.setTitle(name);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

}
}
```

### Output:---

[image]

### Onclick-->

[image]

Comment: It works but now menu not shown in Calendar_date_text.class

Comment: what theme you are using ?darkactionbar or noactionbar in style theme?

Comment: I am using no action bar.

Comment: @HarnoorSingh see my edit...use             setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
 to display menu...i forgot to add that